# Why doesn't my Angular app display images?

Tags: html, angular, firefox, svg

I created a simple `html` file which should display `svg` image:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HelloWorld</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
    <img src="D:/Angular/hello-world/node_modules/bootstrap-icons/icons/star.svg">
</body>

</html>
```

It displays fine in Google Chrome but Firefox displays nothing at all but that's another issue...

When I'm running exactly the same code but in an Angular project inside `index.html` Google Chrome shows the `"couldn't load"` image. Does somebody know why in a pure `html` file it works but when running from Angular project  it stops? And why firefox displays nothing?

Comment: Why did you put absolute path of image ? Put image inside angular assets folder and use that relative path

Comment: Static HTML is what it is: static. It has direct access to the file system. Angular is a web application running in a server. It does not have direct access to the file system. If you need to display static SVG images in Angular, you need to put it in some directory inside Angular source (conventionally called `assets`) and reference it from there.

Comment: Try to define all svg images in `app.component.ts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an Angular app, images need to be in a specific folder for it to be able to find said images. Move (or copy) the image to `src/assets` and use the path `assets/star.svg`.